# How to extract digit and check whether it is prime digit or not in java?

Tags: java

Does anyone know how to take a number, extract its digits and display the digits which are prime numbers?
for ex - 762
Output: 7, 2

I have written the programmed till here:

```
 // program to input a number, print the prime digit, ex - 762 = 7,2
        int n, d, i=1, c=0;
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        n = in.nextInt();
        while (n>0) {
            d = n%10;
            while (i<=d) {
                if (d%i==0) {
                    c++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (c==2) {
                System.out.println(d);
            }
            n = n/10;
        }
```

Output
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNSpE.jpg)

I don't know why the loop is not repeating.
If anyone knows, please help.

Comment: Because you initialize `i` once, at the beginning; in the inner `while` loop you increment `i`, but you never set it back to 1. You probably want to set `i` back to 1 inside the outer `while` loop. This is a good opportunity to learn how to debug your code: step through it with a debugger line by line to follow what happens.

Comment: It's also the case that your code is working it's way from the least significant digit to the most significant digit which is not what your examples shows.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset `i` to 1 with each digit

```
    while (n>0) {
        d = n%10;
        i = 1;
        while (i<=d) {
            if (d%i==0) {
                c++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (c==2) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }
        n = n/10;
    }
```

BTW there are few enough prime numbers in the range to 1 - 9 that you could just manually code in checks for matching if digit is prime (not calculate for each digit)